# Vmware server - 3d graphics upgrade like WKS 7 and vmware player

Tags: vmware-server

Anybody have an idea as to when VMWARE SERVER will have an upgrade to support 3-d graphics etc.

I have created some W7 VM's under WKS7 and an upgraded vmware tools -- the W7 VM's run full aero etc.

I believe that vmware tools and graphics for VM's running under vmware server are at the WKS 6.5 level -- hence problems can occur.

Any info on an upgrade.

Cheers
jimbo

Answer (score 0):

VMware Server is not built for supporting client applications, and if anything, VMware is removing more client functionality from Server in the latest versions.

(GSX previously was similar in functionality to Workstation, and GSX has been renamed Server)

Therefore, the question should have been directed at Workstation & Player.

Furthermore, VMware Workstation 7.1 Beta currently has subpar 3-d graphics performance.

If you really want to hardware assisted graphics in a virtual machine, you want to use Parallels Extreme http://www.parallels.com/products/extreme/

Comment: The question was about VMware Server.

Comment: And you should know that VMware Server is not targeted at supporting desktop applications as a client.  Hence the "Server" part of the name, in the client-server model.

Comment: That's bunk.

Comment: @Chris Thorpe - The virtualization community views VMware Server as crippleware; Workstation is superior for supporting clients.   I hope you are not trying to argue the technical merits of Workstation vs. Parallels Extreme for 3d graphics in VM.....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested the following on VMware Server?

http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_vidsound_d3d_enabling_vm.html